# Template instantiation time typeid()

Tags: c++, templates

How can I find the type of the template argument at template instantiation time? For example, I'd like the following template to instantiate into 2 different functions, depending on the argument:

```
template <typename T> void test(T a) {
    if-T-is-int {
        doSomethingWithInt(a);
    } else {
        doSomethingElse(a);
    }
}
```

When instantiated with an `int`, the resulting function would be:

```
void test(int a) { doSomethingWithInt(a); }
```

and when instantiated with a `float` for example, it would be:

```
void test(float a) { doSomethingElse(a); }
```

Comment: Why not two overloads of a normal function? If you want behaviour for types other than `int` and `float`, that's where you'd start needing the template.

Comment: @chris, what I really have is a larger function that differs slightly in functionality depending on type. So I'm thinking of using your suggestion and then moving the bulk of the code in a separate inline function.

Comment: If it works better, you can use `std::is_same` as well: http://ideone.com/aFONa

Comment: @chris, that happens at runtime though, doesn't it?

Comment: The `if` does, yes, but the `is_same<>::value` is compile-time, and you still see the non-interfering different results. Calling the function would work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it sounds like all you need is two overloaded versions for `int` and `float`. There's no behaviour for other types described, so templates aren't necessary.

```
void test (int i) {
    doSomethingWithInt(i);
}

void test (float f) {
    doSomethingElse(f);
}
```

If you do need the case of other types, add in a normal templated version. The specific overloads take precedence. For an example, [see here](http://ideone.com/ave7I).

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T> void test(T a) {
    doSomethingElse(a);
}

template <> void test(int a) {
    doSomethingWithInt(a);
}
```

Should work, but you need to consider cases where you get an `int &`, `const int`, etc.